Set text of Loading component with new line characters
I am using the Loading component of Element-UI, I want to set the loading text that displays under the spinner with "\n" included for the new line characters. Following is the Vue component code:
     data() {
            return {
              uploadProgressText: "", // New data property for progress text
              numOfFiles: 0,
              numOfFilesSuccesfullyProcessed: 0,
              fileProgress: {},
            }
        }
        methods: {
        initBeforeUpload() {
        this.uploadProgressText = ""; // Reset progress text
        this.fullScreenMask = this.$loading({
                lock: true,
                text: this.uploadProgressText,
                spinner: "el-icon-loading",
                background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
                customClass: "upload-progress-mask", // Custom class for styling
                target: document.body, // Target the entire body
              });
        },
        updateProgressText() {
              // Construct the progress text
              this.uploadProgressText = ${this.numOfFilesSuccesfullyProcessed} / ${this.numOfFiles} files uploaded\n;
              this.uploadProgressText += "<br>";
        
              // Add individual file progress details
              for (const [file, progress] of Object.entries(this.fileProgress)) {
                this.uploadProgressText += ${file}: ${progress}%\n;
              }
        
              this.uploadProgressText.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
              // Update the loading component's text
              if (this.fullScreenMask) {
                this.fullScreenMask.setText(this.uploadProgressText);
              }
            },}

I am calling the updateProgressText method from another method which is not needed here to understand the problem. \n and <br> both are not working here. Everything is displayed on the same line.  I also tried adding CSS:
 body .upload-progress-mask .el-loading-text {
      white-space: pre-wrap; /* Preserves both spaces and line breaks */
    } 

but this is also not working. Please guide.

I set the CSS style to the .el-loading-text class only removing it from scoped CSS. it works.

Does anyone know how to change this text color dynamically?

i have tried \n and use 'white-space: pre-wrap;' on .el-loading-text,it works
